# Number of NUMA nodes and CPU core selection for low latency systems

Tags: linux, cpu, performance, numa

I use an AMD EPYC 9374F CPU with Ubuntu Server 23.04. My goal is having the lowest possible latency.

I am running 1 hot path thread in a core and 3 threads for other admin works. Depending on the NUMA nodes, I'm planning to give 0-3 or 0-7 cores to the OS.

I'd like to learn what would be the benefits of having 1, 2 or 4 NUMA nodes. What are the possible advantages or disadvantages having different number of NUMA nodes?

There is the AMD 3D V-Cache and it made me confused to pick the cores I'd like to pin my threads. Depending on the architecture of the AMD EPYC 9374F CPU, which CPU cores would be the best in terms of cache performance? Or is it possible to isolate the all L3 cache for my threads?

Thanks in advance.